# How to change metadata for audio files in Node.js

Tags: node.js, audio, metadata, albumart

I have an ongoing project, a music streaming website which I'm building from scratch and I want to be able to change the metadata of the audio files that will be uploaded to the site, i.e, change the album art, album, artist, genre, year of release, etc.

I'm using Node.js as my server, how can I achieve this?

Initially went for the Exiftool-vendored package but it wasn't really giving what I wanted, checked other npm packages and I couldn't find one that was worth it, consulted AI and it still wasn't helpful